# Handling big data for apriori

Tags: r, transactions, apriori, arules

I'm trying to run apriori from the arules package and am running into memory issues. So far I can read in the data and split it into the correct format for doing a basket analysis, but when I try to convert my data to a transaction type i'm getting an error due to the size (about 800,000 rows).

Is there any packages that can help me to handle the size of this data?

```
as((split(first2$Product,f = first2$Transaction_Id)),"transactions")
```

I've been stuck on this for about a week now, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many items (columns) you have and how sparse the data is (items per transaction). The apriori implementation in arules requires all transactions to reside in main memory. If you can read in the data but as(data, "transactions") fails, then you can try to directly create a sparse ngCMatrix from package Matrix and use it to create a itemMatrix (which is basically what transactions is).

See

```
R> class? ngCMatrix
R> class? itemMatrix
R> class? transactions
```

Unfortunately this is somewhat painful.